# Laravel validation require at least one array without empty field

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Request inputs are:

```
['posts' =>
    [
        'language_id' => ...,
        'title' => ...,
        'content' => ...
    ],
    .
    .
    .
]
```

So i need at least one not empty post (or at least one post without empty title). For now i decided to make custom validation rule that will be used like: `'posts' => 'at_least_one:title'` that will check if there is at least one post without empty title.

Does anybody know some way to make this possible without making of custom validation rule?

Comment: custom validation will be the great solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $title = isset($post['title']) ? $post['title'] : '';
    if($title ==''){
     /** */
    }else{
      /**   */`
    }`
   }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.